# Удалил случайно файлы на linux mint - " ~/.bashrc и ~/.bash_profile ", как их восстановить

Tags: linux

Можно ли без этих файлов обойтись или эти системные нужные файлы?

Comment: Если после удаления работает всё - значит, можно обойтись. Конкретно `.bashrc` - конфиг-файл, описывающий поведение `bash` этим же самым языком.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да там ничего интересного :) `.bash_profile` у меня, например, вообще нет (mint 17.3). Если очень надо - можно скопировать `.bashrc` из `/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc` и поправить при необходимости.

Comment: на самом деле человек только что мог удалить, например, скрипты для перезапуска реактора на атомной станции.

Comment: Отдел фантастики в другой стороне :)